# Trying to get a long running function to run in background using cakephp and bash shell script

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, background

I have a function in a controller in cakephp which could potentially run for thousands of seconds. The function basically has a list of links and contacts several API's to get various SEO data from them. So each link can take a few seconds each.

I've been trying to get a cake shell set up to do this for me but with no luck. The closest I have come is to have this bash script which runs the required shell with a parameter (30 in this case which is the id of a user on the system.)

```
/home/linkmoni/public_html/cake/console/cake -app /home/linkmoni/public_html/app updateuserlinks 30 > update3.txt 2> update3.err &
```

then call this script from within my controller

```
$result = exec("sh update_links.sh > update2.txt 2> update2.txt");
```

Now, the bash script works if I ssh into my server and run it directly from there. All the links update correctly and everything is fine. When running from php exec there seems to be a problem. As far as I can tell it's to do with a requirement for a user to be logged in.

After running the above code the only text is found in update3.txt

```
Status: 302 Moved Temporarily
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Location: http://linkmoni.com/~linkmoni/links
Content-type: text/html
```

Before I got to this point I tried messing around with wget and session cookies which worked to some extent but required a particular users login credentials. This worked in that it bypassed the systems login, but I couldn't get it to access any of the models data.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work? Basically all I want to do is run this long function in the background, whilst having access to the cakephp models.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: which cake version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute path to your `updateN.txt` files. The web server runs as an unprivileged user, so you might have an issue trying to write to the default working path.

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
USER_ID=$1
WEB_ROOT=/home/linkmoni/public_html
CAKE=${WEB_ROOT}/cake/console/cake
WORK_PATH=/tmp/linkmoni/updateuserlinks
OUTFILE=${WORK_PATH}/update-${USER_ID}.txt
ERRFILE=${WORK_PATH}/update-${USER_ID}.err

mkdir -p ${WORK_PATH}

${CAKE} -app ${WEB_ROOT}/app updateuserlinks ${USER_ID} \
   > ${OUTFILE} 2> ${ERRFILE} &
```

In your app:

```
$result = exec("sh /path/to/update_links.sh > /tmp/linkmoni/update2.txt 2>&1");
```